Overpass-turbo query to retrieve polygon river features
I tried to extract the polygon features for the Kuskokwim River in Alaska, since it's a main-stem and wide river and, thus, represented by polygons at larger scales. But no matter what, I cannot get overpass-turbo to return the polygons. The lines, ways, and nodes are all returned no problem:
[out:json][timeout:60];
// gather results
(
  // Search for ways with the name "Kuskokwim River"
  way["name"="Kuskokwim River"];
  
  // Search for relations with the name "Kuskokwim River"
  relation["name"="Kuskokwim River"];
  
  // Search for multipolygon relations with the name "Kuskokwim River"
  relation["name"="Kuskokwim River"]["type"="multipolygon"];
);

// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;


It seems the river (*riverbank) has too many polygons with holes (too complex for turbo) I found it way quicker to download the Alaska shapefile from  https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/alaska-latest-free.shp.zip and selected the river in gis_osm_water_a_free_1.shp

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/11355925#map=10/61.7130/-158.6137 is an example why it was split up.

Thanks, but i'm still confused because the feature (11255925) is tagged as multipolygon and Kuskokwin. So, why wouldn't this feature be returned?

donuts in the polygon. overpass has limitations.

The polygon(s) does not have the name Kuskokwim River. There is the name hidden in the note tag. Therefore this would provide the polygon:
[out:json][timeout:5];
relation["note"="Kuskokwim River"];
out geom;

But, this is only one segment of the river.
You can get the whole river by search of all ways and/or relations with the given name. After that, search the river tagged polygons around them. The common way to produce the center-nodes is the >; method. But this produce a large number of nodes, the afterwards search is very resource-intensive. Here it is sufficient to get any one node of every way, here we get every 2nd node with node(w:2):
[out:json][timeout:25];
wr["name"="Kuskokwim River"];
node(w:2) -> .setNodes;
wr[water=river](around.setNodes:1000);
out geom;

@ Overpass
A few other rivers are also included. If necessary, these can be reduced  by modifying of the selected nodes number and the search radius (here 1000 m). Or these rivers are also specifically identified by using their name in the same way, and after that subtracted from the main set of the Kuskokwim River (...(.setMain; - .setOther)...).
